# ¿Cómo restarle 3 días a fechas de SQL en C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo este código que me imprime fechas en una lista:

```
public List<DateTime> fechas3()
    {
        List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>();
        List<DateTime> fec = new List<DateTime>();
        SqlConnection cone = new SqlConnection(connect);
        cone.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT DispositionDueDate from fechas ", cone);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            fec.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(reader[0]));
        }
        return fec;
    }
```

Yo quisiera restarle 3 dias a cada fecha de esa lista.

Ejemplos:

```
 20/05/16  =======>>  17/05/16

 15/12/16  =======>>   12/12/16
```

Comment: SELECT GETDATE() - 3, GETDATE() - 2, GETDATE () - 1

Comment: podrías colocar la consulta y colocar mejor el problema que estas teniendo

Comment: ¿Nos podrías mostrar tu avance y una explicación más detallada del problema que tienes? De igual forma, edita tu pregunta y adjunta código para darnos una idea de qué es realmente lo que necesitas.

Comment: Como podria restarle tres dias a esa fecha y mostarla ya con los 3 dias menos?

Comment: pon un ejemplo para comprender mejor lo que quieres hacer

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from tabla 
where campo_fecha >= DATEADD(day, -3, fecha_comparar) and campo_fecha <= fecha_comparar
```

Comment: el campo fecha_comparer cual es, la que yo tengo en la base de datos??

Comment: Es la fecha que deseas comparar ejemplo: 'YYYY-MM-DD  00:00:00'

Comment: +1 pq nunca entendi el punto negativo sobre esta respuesta. Es escueta pero soluciona el problema.

Answer (score 2):

Solo cambia la siguiente linea

```
fec.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(reader[0]));
```

por la siguiente linea

```
fec.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(reader[0]).AddDays(-3));
```

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que tu campo `DispositionDueDate` es de tipo `DATETIME`, solo tienes que restar el número de días que necesitas. Tu comanando de SQL quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ((DispositionDueDate) - 3) AS DispositionDueDate FROM fechas ", cone);
```

Answer (score 1):

Suena como que quieres manipular las fechas desde C#. De ser el caso, puedes usar el método [`DateTime.AddDays`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx) con un parámetro negativo para restar 3 días.

Por ejemplo, partiendo de tu lista de fechas `fec`, el código siguiente te genera una nueva lista con todas las fechas menos 3 días:

```
List<DateTime> nuevaLista = fec.Select(dt => dt.AddDays(-3)).ToList();
```

Comment: A mi me suena tambien que la operación se tiene que hacer en el codigo no en la consulta